# How to select a range of rows but offset it from a specific id

Tags: mysql, sql

If I want to select , let's say, 5 records, I do this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 5
```

If I want to add an offset, I do this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable OFFSET 5 LIMIT 5;
```

But what should I do if I want to offset from a specific id? Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable OFFSET FROM id = 30 IMIT 5
```

Comment: there is an id in the URI, I get that ID, show a list of its preceding/following items up/down to 10 items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `limit` without an `order by` is to be discouraged.  Let me assume this is what you want:

```
select *
from mytable
where id >= 30
order by id
limit 5;
```